# How can I add a video for each language & put it in an settings menu (like sharing)? (JW8)

Tags: jwplayer

Some of my videos have multiple language-versions which I'd like to represent in a settings menu - just like it would work with multiple audio tracks.

The videos are in mp4 as well as the original video, I don't have a m3u8-file ready.

Does anybody know a way how to implement this?
I could create a custom settings menu and render the file-source and video-switch myself, but didn't find a way to create a custom settings menu either.

Hope somebody can give me a hint.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use each MP4 as a separate source and make the label the name of the language.

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
    sources: [{
        file: 'english.mp4',
        label: 'English',
    },{
        file: 'spanish.mp4',
        label: 'Spanish',
    },{
        file: 'italian.mp4',
        label: 'Italian',
    },{
        file: 'french.mp4',
        label: 'French',
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! In my case, I've got languages as well as different qualities/sources, with that solution I would have to choose between them two for a clean experience, but it's a nice idea/workaround. I ended up realizing it as I described in my initial post - it's a button which fires a custom div now (imitating the style of the settings menu).